# How to use TensorFlow lite in Android with custom model for audio recognition

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have example of TensorFlow lite Android and i want to implement my custom trained model for audio recognition. I have trained model using custom [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S4_bbE0kgt-98HrOTM1BY-et58esZYVq/view?usp=sharing) using [this](https://github.com/ShawnHymel/tflite-speech-recognition) tutorial. I want to implement that model to TensorFlow lite Android project but it gives following error :

```
Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.speech, PID: 22892
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input Tensor index: 1
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.getInputTensor(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:287)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:136)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:311)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.speech.SpeechActivity.recognize(SpeechActivity.java:424)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.speech.SpeechActivity.access$400(SpeechActivity.java:73)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.speech.SpeechActivity$4.run(SpeechActivity.java:373)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have use the TensorFlow lite android [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/speech_commands/android) of speech recognition and replace their tflite model to my custom dataset model

Comment: It shows that you are inserting the wrong input tensor. Have you printed input and output tensor shapes of interpreter inside android app first to have a look what is expected?

Comment: Could you share your code as well? Maybe use tensor index 0 instead and try?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same error while adapting the TF Lite sample for Android by Google to my personal ASR project, similarly to yours. I have fixed it by deleting the statement `tfLite.resizeInput(1, new int[] {1});` in the method `onCreate` from the `SpeechActivity`, since my custom model (as well as yours, I believe) has only one input tensor, differently from the original model provided by Google, which considers two input tensors.